# How to get the Content of Button in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, button, mvvm

I have a button with Command set to viewModel. Button at runtime populating with values. 
Can anybody help me to get the button Content in the viewModel?

4 buttons with 4 different set of values at runtime, and based in the button click I will take action. Say out of 4 buttons 2nd button is click then I will minus 100 from score. and if 4th Button is clicked then I will add 40 in the scrore. This 100 and 40 is the buttons content.

```
<Button Height="110" Width="230" Content="{Binding Path=ListOfValues[1]}" />
<Button Height="110" Width="230" Content="{Binding Path=ListOfValues[2]}" />
<Button Height="110" Width="230" Content="{Binding Path=ListOfValues[3]}" />
<Button Height="110" Width="230" Content="{Binding Path=ListOfValues[4]}" />
```

Can anybody help me to get the buttons values at runtime at viewModel?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like WPF but tagged as jquery. Are you ListOfValues not on the ViewModel anyway?

Comment: yes ListOfValues is in viewmodel, through notify changes I bound those values to 4 buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for WPF - does something like this help?

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfCommandTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="DoSomethingCommand" Text="Do Something" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource DoSomethingCommand}" Executed="OnDoSomethingExecuted" />
    </Grid.CommandBindings>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Bind the commandParameter to the button content -->
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Button1" Command="{StaticResource DoSomethingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button2" Command="{StaticResource DoSomethingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Button3" Command="{StaticResource DoSomethingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace WpfCommandTest
```

{
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void OnDoSomethingExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Look at e.Parameter   <---!!!This line gives you the value of button content
    }
}
```

}

The idea is to use the command parameter...

Comment: The idea is great, but I am implementing a Windows Phone 8 game and there "<Grid.CommandBindings>" is missing, any idea how can I do that in Windows Phone 8, because in WP8 its phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources

Comment: Im not that familiar with WP8 - does the root level node (i.e window or equivalent) have a command bindings section? You can specify the commandbindings as a resource at any parent level, so that child elements can bind correctly... hth!

Comment: root level does not have command bindings. That's the issue here, any other way I can get the content. My apps is WP8.

Comment: Ok - did a quick google - you can use commands with wp8, you just have t declare them in the code behind - See this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM#example1

Comment: Thanks @Jay your suggestions definitely helped me. Can you give me one more idea, is it possible to trigger animation from ViewModel to view. Like RotateTransform or Storyboard animation, kind of animation is it a good practice? How can I do that?

Comment: @Debhere Yes, I know it is possible, but it is nothing I have actually tried to do. My understanding is that you can bind a trigger to a custom property (dependency or INotifyPropertyChanged) and when the property changes, your trigger will activate. I'm afraid I won't be able to give you any guidance when it comes to best practices for the same reason (I've never had the need to do it!) Best of luck with your WP8 app!

Answer (score 2):

While command binding for the button, provide command parameter as the content of the button

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}
```

Comment: This helped me but I marked previous one as solution that's more elaborate. Thanks