# Accessing UI controls in Viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have Stackpanel with Buttons as follows,

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 10 0 0" Name="mystack">
    <Button Width="30" Name="btn1" Height="30" Content="1" Margin="10"/>
    <Button Width="30"  Height="30" Content="2" Margin="10"/>
    <Button Width="30"  Height="30" Content="3" Margin="10"/>
    <Button Width="30" Height="30" Content="4" Margin="10"/>
</StackPanel>
```

How to make these buttons as single object and use that in viewmodel?
because I have to check each and every buttons "Content" with my viewmodel property..

Comment: You should *never* access UI controls in the view model, it breaks the pattern.

Comment: yes But have to do that checking..

Comment: You should just bind the properties of interest (like `Content`) and interact with that data, not the controls directly.

Comment: yeah ok @H.B thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a binding.

```
Content={Binding SomePropertyInYourViewModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add button command and button command parameter to the button

```
<Button Content="Button1" Command="{StaticResource DoSomethingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
```

this link may help you [How to get the Content of Button in ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302902/how-to-get-the-content-of-button-in-viewmodel)

this is how to add command in MVVM

```
    public class ViewModelBase
    {
      public ViewModelBase()
      {
       _canExecute = true;
      }
      private ICommand _doSomethingCommand;
      public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
      {
        get
        {
         return _doSomethingCommand ?? (_doSomethingCommand = new CommandHandler(() => MyAction(), _canExecute));
         }
      }
       private bool _canExecute;
       public void MyAction()
       {

       }
     }
     public class CommandHandler : ICommand
     {
       private Action _action;
       private bool _canExecute;
        public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute)
        {
         _action = action;
         _canExecute = canExecute;
         }

         public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
         return _canExecute;
         }

         public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

         public void Execute(object parameter)
         {
             _action();
          }
        }
```

Comment: how to get that command values in viewmodel? that example takes value in code behind..